# Can I join multilpe tables from multiple database across different servers?

Tags: php, database, cakephp

Is it possible to write `join` query between multiple databases across different servers?

Is it possible?

Comment: if you have to join multiple tables that are across different databases *AND* servers then you need to really rethink the design.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is, **Yes it is possible.**

But since you have not specified any particular situation you are facing,it is not possible to give a direct answer.

In MySQL it can be done using [The FEDERATED Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html).

However I suggest you go through following SO questions

1. [Join tables from two different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114197/join-tables-from-two-different-server)
2. [Joining tables across multiple servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269098/joining-tables-across-multiple-servers)
3. [MySQL Cross Server Select Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810349/mysql-cross-server-select-query)
4. [MySQL — join between tables in 2 different databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698378/mysql-join-between-tables-in-2-different-databases)
5. [How To Left Join 2 Tables On 2 Different Databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685193/how-to-left-join-2-tables-on-2-different-databases)
6. [Connecting multiple database and join query across database in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895892/connecting-multiple-database-and-join-query-across-database-in-php)